# C++ dynamic memory allocation weird output

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm learning about dynamic memory allocation in C++. On running the code below, different output is printed every time.

```
char *const dynamic_array = new char[50];
dynamic_array[0] = '\0';
dynamic_array[0] = 'a';
cout << dynamic_array << endl;
delete[] dynamic_array;
```

Example output(s) of 5 runs:

- aδ
- aδ
- aⁿ
- aΓ
- aε

why is the output different on some runs ?

Comment: UB. You print a non-nul terminated string, with uninitialised values after the 1st to boot. Next!

Comment: Do you think it makes any difference that you first write `'\0'` and then `'a'` in the same place, compared to just writing `'a'` directly?

Comment: @molbdnilo got it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unrelated to dynamic memory allocation but only to the legacy C string. A C string is a **null terminated** char array. As you failed to properly write a null character (`'\0'`) after the `'a'`, using it as a C string is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The `operator<<` you are calling here:

```
cout << dynamic_array << endl;
```

Expects a pointer to the first element of a null-terminated character array. Your character array is not null-terminated, hence your code has undefined behavior.

If you want a dynamically sized string you should write:

```
std::string dynamic_array{"a"};
std::cout << dynamic_array;
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with dynamic memory allocation.  Your code would have failed even if you had used a fixed local array without `new[]`:

```cpp
char fixed_array[50];
fixed_array[0] = '\0';
fixed_array[0] = 'a';
cout << fixed_array << endl;
```

You are calling the overloaded `operator<<` that takes a **nul-terminated** `char*` string as input, but you are simply putting the `'\0'` terminator in the wrong array element.

Use this instead:

```cpp
char *const dynamic_array = new char[50];
dynamic_array[0] = 'a';
dynamic_array[1] = '\0'; // <-- index 1, not 0!
cout << dynamic_array << endl;
delete[] dynamic_array;
```

```cpp
char fixed_array[50];
fixed_array[0] = 'a';
fixed_array[1] = '\0'; // <-- index 1, not 0!
cout << fixed_array << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++, variables and objects need to be ***declared*** and ***initialized***, but depending on whether a particular variable is a local variable, a class-member variable or a global/static variable, their default initialization may be done by the compiler or not, following the rules described here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

In short it means that local variables don't get default-initialized, while static/global variables get default-initialized. What concerns to class member-variables, if there's no member-initialization syntax present in constructors (which is the case for the default-constructor), then they'll get default initialized as well.

Another thing to remember regarding this uninitialized-variable issue and other undefined behaviors in C++ is that some compilers may decide (based on some heuristics or by default) to default-initialize all variables upon their declaration to avoid run-time logic errors, which may not always be desirable (mostly due to performance reasons), but it's possible to disable those. A good starting point for reading about this is here: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/uninitialized-variables-and-undefined-behavior/